# Android substring

Tags: java, android, string

What is an efficient way to get number 17 from the following path?

```
/contacts/lookup/1217x31-2BN8629/17/data
```

It works with

```
substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') - 2, path.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

But then it is hardcoded for a number 10-99, and if a number is for example 3, it will return /3 etc.

Comment: You could find all / in your string, get their index and than get the substring.

Comment: You are searching for the index twice.  Use a local variable instead and only search once.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not safely answerable, as you've failed to specify *what* about the representative "17" you want to base the extraction on.   If we saw a lot of other cases we might be able to do deduce that - but the point about rules is that they need to distinguish what you want from what you don't, and we can only guess at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest, IMHO, would be to split the string according to the `/` character, and take the before-last element:

```
String[] parts = str.split("/");
String result = parts[parts.length - 2];
```

Answer (score 2):

First: perform each operation only once.  Use a local variable to store data that you will need a second time.

Second: you can look for the next '/' character once you have found the last one.

Eg:

```
final int lastSlashIndex = path.lastIndexOf('/');
final int nextToLastSlashIndex = path.lastIndexOf('/', lastSlashIndex-1);
path.substring(nextToLastSlashIndex+1, lastSlashIndex);
```